# C++: Vector subscript out of range when trying to fill multiple vectors with getlline() in a single for loop

Tags: c++, vector, range

When I try to run this code:

```
vector <string> names;
vector <string> telephones;
vector <string> emails;

for (int i = 0; i < 5;i++) {
    cout << "enter name" << '\n';
    getline(cin, names[i]);

    cout << "enter telephone number" << '\n';
    getline(cin, telephones[i]);

    cout << "enter email address" << '\n';
    getline(cin, emails[i]);
}
```

It compiles fine but when I try to run it, I get the "vector subscript out of range" error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please define size of your vectors because just defining the vectors does not allocate memory to them.

```
vector <string> names(5);
vector <string> telephones(5);
vector <string> emails(5);

for (int i = 0; i < 5;i++) {
    cout << "enter name" << '\n';
    getline(cin, names[i]);

    cout << "enter telephone number" << '\n';
    getline(cin, telephones[i]);

    cout << "enter email address" << '\n';
    getline(cin, emails[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of your vectors are given a starting size or increased in size with any of the push or emplace functions. You cannot use the `[]` until you have caused storage to be allocated.

Give

```
cout << "enter name" << '\n';
string temp;
getline(cin, temp);
names.push_back(temp);
```

etc... a try.

Sidenote:

Rather than having three arrays of one piece of data, consider making a structure

```
struct person
{
    string name;
    string telephone;
    string email
};
```

and then a single vector of this structure.

```
vector<person> people;
```

This sets you up to create a function that reads a whole person in one crack, making the main loop logic much simpler and require less maintenance if you add more data to `person` in the future.

```
person getPerson()
{
    person temp;
    cout << "enter name" << '\n';
    getline(cin, temp.name);

    cout << "enter telephone number" << '\n';
    getline(cin, temp.telephone);

    cout << "enter email address" << '\n';
    getline(cin, temp.email);
    return temp;
}
```

and then

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5;i++) {
    people.push_back(getPerson());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't directly take input in vector. Because when you run getline(cin, name[i]) there is no allocated 'i' index in this vector. there is two possible solution.

solution 1, first allocate all index:

```
vector <string> names;
vector <string> telephones;
vector <string> emails;
name.resize(5);
telephones.resize(5);
emails.resize(5);

for (int i = 0; i < 5;i++) {
    cout << "enter name" << '\n';
    getline(cin, names[i]);

    cout << "enter telephone number" << '\n';
    getline(cin, telephones[i]);

    cout << "enter email address" << '\n';
    getline(cin, emails[i]);
}
```

Solution 2, create index in runtime:

```
vector <string> names;
vector <string> telephones;
vector <string> emails;

for (int i = 0; i < 5;i++) {
    string temp;
    cout << "enter name" << '\n';
    getline(cin, temp);
    name.push_back(temp);

    cout << "enter telephone number" << '\n';
    getline(cin, temp);
    telephones.push_back(temp);

    cout << "enter email address" << '\n';
    getline(cin, temp);
    emails.push_back(temp);
}
```